# Delete hibernate entity which is referenced by @ManyToMany in other entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I want to delete Recipe (using spring data DAO) but I got SQL exception: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "recipe" violates foreign key constraint "fkacys689tmdmfggtf4thdoc83k" on table "favourite_recipes"
  Detail: Key (id)=(76823) is still referenced from table "favourite_recipes".`

My entities:

```
@Entity
public class Account {

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinTable(name = "favourite_recipes",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "account_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id"))
  private Set<Recipe> favouriteRecipes = new HashSet<>(0);

  ...
}


@Entity
public class Recipe {
  ...
}
```

How to remove recipe instance?

Comment: how are u trying to delete it?

Comment: simply `recipeDao.delete(recipeId);`
where `recipeDao` is bean created using spring data (interface extending `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Amer Qarabsa metioned I had to remove recipe from Account.

1. I added new field in Recipe to get bidirectional mapping

   ```
   @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, mappedBy = "favouriteRecipes")
   private Set<Account> recipeLovers = new HashSet<>(0);
   ```
2. Code in service class to remove recipe from all accounts + clear lovers in recipe (recipe and recipeId variables are not initialized here)

   ```
   Set<Account> recipeLovers = recipe.getRecipeLovers();
   recipeLovers.forEach(account ->
       account.getFavouriteRecipes()
           .removeIf(r -> r.getId() == recipeId));
   recipeLovers.clear();
   recipeDao.delete(recipe);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the cascade type, by default is set to ALL.

For example you can work around the contraints like this:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
```

more info : [cascade type docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/metamodel/binding/CascadeType.html)

Comment: It seems that the default value is "no operations being cascaded" http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html#cascade()

Comment: It's not working. I tried with DETACH and ALL. I''m not deleting Account which is owner of this relationship but Recipe which may be referenced there.
I don't want to iterate over all accounts and check their favourite recipes.
Can I do it more efficiently?
Should I add reference in Recipe to Accounts where its set as favourite or implement custom query or can I use simple annotations to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

in you need to delete from the owning entity side which is the Account.

So first remove the recipe from recipe list in Account and save the account, then remove the recipe itself.

Comment: It's not option. I can't iterate over all accounts in system.

Comment: why iterate, you have set, remove time is constant

Comment: It's about favourite recipes - every account can have this recipe in favourites.

Comment: ok but you are storing your recipies in a SET , with the right hashcode you will be removing the recipe with access time so no iterating around here